# Why is it still mandatory to land a plane without autopilot?

Tags: landing, autopilot

I know that there are runways in the world that operate CAT III where the pilot can land with autopilot. But why do most airports with ILS not allow automatic landing?

Comment: Landings are fun.

Comment: @DeepSpace I'm confused, sorry. I will correct the question. CAT III is what I wanted to say.

Comment: If an airport is in a location that only gets 1 0-visibility day every 2 years, there is no reason to install such a system.

Comment: Not allow, or not equipped for?  Those are two very different things.